# Energy problem taken from classical mechanics by john r taylor

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

hi for the following problem i know the method to do it, im just struggling when it comes to evaluating the required methods as i havent seen one like this before,heres the problem

" a Charge $q$ in a uniform electric Field $E_0$ experiences a constant force $F=qE_0$"
 part a is to show that this force is conservative, to do this i need to show that the curl of $F$ is equal to 0 as my understanding is telling me The problem is actually calculating the Curl as i have no idea what to do with the $ E_0$ term, do i need to write it in a different form before i evaluate it directly?

The second part is verify that the potential energy of the charge at position $r$ is $U(r)=-qE_0.r$ again i'm having issues when evaluating the integral. if someone could show me how to evaluate these i would be extremly greatful.

this problem is 4.17 in the text book however the solutions in the back of the book is just for odd numbered questions

Comment: ?$\quad LATEX\quad$?

Answer (score 0):

So
$$
E_0 = (E_{01}, E_{02}, E_{03})^T = \text{const}
$$
a vector of three constant real numbers and
$$
F = q E_0
$$
thus that constant vector multiplied by a constant scalar $q$, giving a constant force vector $F$ and
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{curl}{curl}
(\curl F)_i 
= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j F_k
= \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j (q E_{0k})
= 0
$$
because a partial derivative of a constant is zero.

If $U(r) = -q E_0 \cdot r$ then
\begin{align}
F 
&= -\grad U \\
&= -\grad (-q E_0 \cdot r) \\
&= q \grad(E_0 \cdot r) \\
&= q \grad(E_{01}x_1 + E_{02}x_2 + E_{03} x_3) \\
&= q (E_{01} \grad x_1 + E_{02} \grad x_2 + E_{03} \grad x_3) \\
&= q (E_{01}(1,0,0)^T + E_{02}(0,1,0)^T + E_{03}(0,0,1)^T) \\
&= qE_0
\end{align}
so we can recover the force, the potential fits up to some constant, meaning $U(r) + C$ would give that force as well. To single out that $U(r)$ the requirement $U(0) = 0$ must exist.

From the other direction:
$$
dU = -dW = -F \cdot dr 
$$
gives
$$
U(r) - U(0) 
= \int\limits_0^r dU \\
= - \int\limits_0^r F \cdot dr' \\
= - q \int\limits_0^r E_0 \cdot dr' \\
= - q E_0 \cdot \int\limits_0^r dr' \\
= -q E_0 \cdot (r - 0) \\
= -q E_0 \cdot r
$$

Comment: Thank you for this I was getting confused when writing out the components of E I was writing E_x etc and thinking that it was a variable any possibility you would be able to help me with the second part?

Comment: sorry i wrote down the wrong thing for part b it was to determine the potential energy of the charge at the position r, i know that the answer is -qE_0.r  but this is from guess work since i dont know how to evaluate the integral

Comment: @mathdeds I updated my answer.